# Eclipse libraries could not be imported

Tags: java, eclipse, import

The import function is not working properly. Its showing package java.awt is not accessible, javafx cannot be resolved. It is getting compiled  in blueJ so no problem with the code how to resolve this issue in Eclipse

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to provide us with a clear explanation of your problem and if possible, try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried so far? What research did you do until now?

Comment: When I wrote import java.awt.*;        An error is popping in eclipse showing java.awt is not accessible